# How to use Excel to get a Function Equation from a trendline?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am struggling with Excel right now. What I have is a graph which can be approximated by a polynominal formula. I have values for X and Y Axis and want to get the equation of the trendline. To stay flexible I want a solution which is capable of handling different degrees with "n" possibilites such as y = x0 + z1*x1^2 + z2*x2^2 + ... + zn*xn^n.

Now I assumed that I can Use RGP() (German Excel version of the LINEST() function in English) but I get totally different results compared to the result of a trendline i put into the diagram (excel can show the formulas of trendlines in diagrams).

What I did is:

- Column U: All Y Values (10 values)
- Column V: All X Values (10)
- Column W: All Y^2 Values
- Column X: All X^3 Values
- Column Y: All X^4 Values

Matrix Formula in AA4:AE4 with =RGP(V3:V12;W3:Y12;1;1)

The Results are 4 Different Values. But they have nothing to do with the results I got from the Excel Diagram and the automatically calculated line.

Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Attached the example list I have:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ Col U ║ Col V ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 10    ║ 272.2 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 20    ║ 137.8 ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 30    ║ 77    ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 40    ║ 46.7  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 50    ║ 30.3  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 60    ║ 20.7  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 70    ║ 14.8  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 80    ║ 11    ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 90    ║ 8.5   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ 100   ║ 6.7   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: I managed to solve it. The results with the function TREND() are perfect. TY

Comment: I have cleaned up the comments in preparation to migrate this to SuperUser.  Please consider providing a self-answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. The results with the function TREND() are perfect.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to include enough details that it can be used by somebody else with a similar problem.